# How does the Random generator work in elm?

Tags: random, elm

I am having problem understanding how Random generators were suppose to work.

[image]
In the following example I'm trying to roll two dices on click,
https://ellie-app.com/d9rXQHpfJa1/1

but 'm getting

```
Function generate is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

Random.Generator ( Int, Int )
But it is:

( Random.Generator Int, Random.Generator Int )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is giving you a strong hint that you are attempting to pass in a parameter that doesn't fit with what is expected. Elm does a lot of type inference and since `NewFace (Int, Int)` is a constructor that takes a tuple of two integers, that's what it expects for the second parameter passed to `generate`.

If you visit the [Random package documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Random), you'll see a function that takes two generators and gives you back a generator that uses the first two in a tuple. It is called [`Random.pair`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Random#pair), and if you were to use it in your code, it would look like this:

```elm
( model, Random.generate NewFace (Random.pair (Random.int 1 6) (Random.int 1 6 )))
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without calling Random.pair? I want to do this with as little assist from elm as possible to understand how it works.

Comment: Sure thing! `pair` is the same as `map2 (,)`. If you want to go down the rabbit hole, the [source is available on github](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/06715ed57215325d457f8cf4e0538a69df3b10ee/src/Random.elm#L177-L179)

Comment: thanks, but is there a core api that can interpret 2 generators?

Comment: `pair` (or `map2 (,)`) _is_ the way to handle two generators: it converts two generators that you pass it into a single `Generator (a, b)` value. The Random package gives you the building blocks to construct more complex generators, most often through mapping (`mapX` functions) or binding via `andThen`.